# Como puedo sacar de una lista de listas alguna lista todas las listas que tengan un elemento en comun y guardarlas en otra lista?

Tags: python, lista

quisiera sacar todas las listas que tengan un elemento repetido y ponerlas en otra lista.

Por ejemplo, todas las listas que tengan 4.8, sacar toda la lista en donde esta ese numero y moverlo a una lista diferente.

He intentado de todo pero no me da.

```
`output = [['71023567', 5], 
['34987567', 4.8], 
['34987567', 4.8], 
['34987567', 4.8], 
['32276123', 4.7], 
['89122456', 4.7], 
['00014301503', 4.3], 
['1037678471', 3.2], 
['1036765245', 2.3]]
`
```

Comment: "He intentado todo"... ¿Qué has intentado? Por favor agrega el código con lo que has intentado. En este sitio es importante mostrar un esfuerzo por resolver tus propias preguntas ya que no resolvemos tareas/proyectos, proveemos ayuda a quienes intentan por su cuenta.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Como te indican, el camino acá no es "intenté y no sirvió" sino traer el intento, los errores, los datos deprueba como ya los pusiste y permitir que los demás te ayudemos sobre tu intento, no que te hagamos. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Si señores, es mi primera pregunta. Ya corrijo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres decir que 'repeticiones de elementos' significa: todos los elementos de cada lista de la lista y si el orden también cuenta, pandas sirve bien en este caso:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/default.asp

Dataframe.duplicated() te ayuda:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

```
output = [
  ['71023567', 5],
 ['34987567', 4.8],
 ['34987567', 4.8],
 ['34987567', 4.8],
 ['32276123', 4.7],
 ['89122456', 4.7],
 ['00014301503', 4.3],
 ['1037678471', 3.2],
 ['1036765245', 2.3]
]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(output)

repeticiones = df[df.duplicated()].values.tolist()

print(repeticiones)

# Resultado:
# [['34987567', 4.8], ['34987567', 4.8]]
```

Supongo que sí cuando veo que los elementos que terminan con 4.7 tienen un elemento en la primera posición diferente.

```
 ['32276123', 4.7],
 ['89122456', 4.7],
```

Comment: El op dió el 4.8 como ejemplo. Podrías decir que tiene que hacer con los demás casos por favor?

Comment: Cambié la respuesta según este comentario (Disculpa!)

Comment: No te preocupes, todos nos equivocamos c:

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Me sirvio mucho!

Comment: @WilliamMelo, Buen día, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato, ya si señor, ya la acepto.